# Convertir String a Json en php

Tags: php

No puedo convertir un `string` a un `json`, cuando intento con `json_decode()` me retorna un valor `null`.

Los `string` que intento convertir son como estos:

> [{ id: 6, text: "10", item: 0}, { id: 7, text: "45", item: 1}, { id: 8, text: "3^2", item: 2}, { id: 9, text: "6", item: 3}, { id: 10, text: "666", item: 4}]

o este:

> [{ id: 11, text: "18", item: 0}, { id: 12, text: "16", item: 1}, { id: 13, text: "36", item: 2}]

y ese otro:

> [{ id: 14, text: "12", item: 0}, { id: 15, text: "55", item: 1}, { id: 16, text: "111", item: 2}, { id: 17, text: "9", item: 3}]

Son ejemplos de lo que intento  convertir y lo intento de la siguiente manera:

`json_decode($valores[$clave]["respuestas"])`

Comment: ¿json_encode o json_decode?

Comment: ¿has intentado [validar la estructura de json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348152/detect-bad-json-data-in-php-json-decode) para ver si está correctamente armado?

Comment: @Shaz disculpa, ya lo corregi es `json_decode()`

Comment: @ReneLimon probe como dices `if ($data === null
    && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo "incorrect data";
}` y efectivamente entra en el `if`.

Comment: al utilizar [este](https://jsonlint.com/) validador, en efecto, el error está en las comillas

Comment: @ReneLimon Cambien acabo de validar el `json` en [***esta pagina***](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) y me dijo que el error esta en las comillas de las `key`, no sabia que existían paginas para validarlos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error esta en las comillas de las `key` simplemente las agregue para obtener un valor como este:

> [{ "id": 6, "text": "10", "item": 0}, { "id": 7, "text": "45", "item": 1}, { "id": 8, "text": "3^2", "item": 2}, { "id": 9, "text": "6", "item": 3}, { "id": 10, "text": "666", "item": 4}]

Y en efecto `json_decode()` funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 4):

Tu JSON es incorrecto, **te faltan las comillas en los nombres de elementos**.

Prueba con este JSON:

```
[{
    "id": 6,
    "text": "10",
    "item": 0
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "text": "45",
    "item": 1
}, {
    "id": 8,
    "text": "3^2",
    "item": 2
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "text": "6",
    "item": 3
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "text": "666",
    "item": 4
}]
```

El código que he utilizado para probar si le gusta el JSON a PHP es este, por si quieres hacer más pruebas:

```
<?php
$txt = '[{
    "id": 6,
    "text": "10",
    "item": 0
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "text": "45",
    "item": 1
}, {
    "id": 8,
    "text": "3^2",
    "item": 2
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "text": "6",
    "item": 3
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "text": "666",
    "item": 4
}]';


$var = json_decode($txt);

var_dump($var);

switch(json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - Sin errores';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Excedido tamaño máximo de la pila';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Desbordamiento de buffer o los modos no coinciden';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Encontrado carácter de control no esperado';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Error de sintaxis, JSON mal formado';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Caracteres UTF-8 malformados, posiblemente están mal codificados';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Error desconocido';
        break;
    }
```